# PHP and Xpath - Get node from inner text

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I have the following XML structure

```
<url>
  <loc>some-text</loc>
</url>

<url>
  <loc>some-other-text</loc>
</url>
```

My goal is to get `loc` node from it's inner text (i.e. `some-text`) or a part of it (i.e. `other-text`). Here's my best attempt:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$doc->load($filename);
$xpath = new Domxpath($doc);
$locs = $xpath->query('/url/loc');

foreach($locs as $loc) {
    if(preg_match("/other-text/i", $loc->nodeValue)) return $loc->parentNode;
}
```

Is it possible to get specific `loc` node without iterating over all nodes, simply using xpath query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a query like `//url/loc[contains(., "other-text")]`

---

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<root>
<url>
  <loc>some-text</loc>
</url>

<url>
  <loc>some-other-text</loc>
</url>
</root>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//url/loc[contains(., "other-text")]') as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node);
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
<loc>some-other-text</loc>
```